# What is syntax error with my JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

Would anyone please tell me what is wrong with the following code? I am completely new to javascript, and I know there is a missing comma somewhere. Thanks.

```js
var cake = {
  firstIngredient: "milk",
  secondIngredient: "eggs",
  thirdIngredient: "cakemix",
  bakeTime: 22
  bakeTemp: 420
  mixingInstructions: function() {
    return "Add "
    this.firstIngredient + " to " + this.secondIngredient + " and stir with " + this.thirdIngredient + " and bake at " + bakeTemp + " for " + bakeTime + " minutes.";
  }
};
```

Comment: If you saw this error in your developer's console, you could simply click the  link to the line number and it would take you to the exact line the issue is on. From there, you should really be able to see how that line is different from the lines before it that are not generating the error.

Comment: Missing: comma after `22`, comma after `420`, and `+` sign after `"Add "`.

Answer (score 2):

bakeTime and bakeTemp are both missing commas after them. So is the mixingInstructions function, but it isn't necessary yet.

Comment: I see, but it still doesn't run properly after I put them there.

Comment: @user230517 what does "run properly" mean? Your question was what's the syntax error and Stephen L explained it to you.

Comment: More specifically, the numbers 22, and 420.  I added the commas and it works.

Comment: You are also missing the a `+` after `return "Add"`

Comment: Now my code is successfully run, thanks, however, how do I induce it? I try console.log(cake), it only print out the code, not the string that I expect as a recipe, what's the method to print out the result as string in javascript, like print() in python, thanks.

Comment: `console.log` is the main method to print something. Your problem is **what** you're printing, not how. The recipes are built dynamically via a function call to `mixingInstructions` so you must do exactly that, i.e. `console.log(cake.mixingInstructions());`

Comment: @user230517 if you look at the [answer by 2by2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44167477/3928341), you can see a working solution.

Comment: @nem035 thanks, just like object class in python.

Comment: @nem035 and this. just like self. in python. cool. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have missing commas just after `bakeTime` and `bakeTemp`, and you have missing `this` here `" and bake at " + bakeTemp + " for " + bakeTime` in your function.

```js
var cake = {
  firstIngredient: "milk",
  secondIngredient: "eggs",
  thirdIngredient: "cakemix",
  bakeTime: 22,
  bakeTemp: 420,
  mixingInstructions: function() {
    return "Add " +
    this.firstIngredient + " to " + this.secondIngredient + " and stir with " + this.thirdIngredient + " and bake at " + this.bakeTemp + " for " + this.bakeTime + " minutes.";
  }
};

console.log(cake.mixingInstructions())
```

Comment: missing `this`???

Comment: yes he's not using `this` inside the function here `bake at " + bakeTem`

Comment: Oh I see, my bad. You might as well mention the missing `+` symbol as well then

Answer (score 2):

Follow-up on @Stephen L,

And you forgot to put plus after `>>>>> return "Add " +`

Answer (score 2):

You're also missing a "+" after return "Add "

Answer (score 2):

---

You have these 3 errors:

1. Missing commas after 
     bakeTime: 22
     bakeTemp: 420
2. Missing `+` After `"Add"`
3. Missing `this.` in `bakeTemp` and `bakeTime` in return string

   `return "Add " + this.firstIngredient + " to " + this.secondIngredient + " and stir with " + this.thirdIngredient + " and bake at " + this.bakeTemp + " for " + this.bakeTime + " minutes.";`

```js
    var cake = {
      firstIngredient: "milk",
      secondIngredient: "eggs",
      thirdIngredient: "cakemix",
      bakeTime: 22,
      bakeTemp: 420,
      mixingInstructions: function() {
        return "Add "+ 
this.firstIngredient + " to " + this.secondIngredient + " and stir with " + this.thirdIngredient + " and bake at " + this.bakeTemp + " for " + this.bakeTime + " minutes.";
      }
    };
console.log(cake.mixingInstructions());
```